# Plot 3 variables in view similiar to ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

Is there any function to plot vectors in form $(x,y,z)$ where first coordinate is X value, second- Y value and color of square represents third coordinate? It should look like ArrayPlot.

Here is a sample of my data (http://pastebin.com/nHprReDu) and the results I obtain using `ListDensityPlot`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html) will deal with data in that format. An interpolation order of zero will reproduce the "blocky" `ArrayPlot` output as well.

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, Sin[x] + Sin[y]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}], 1];
ListDensityPlot[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Thank you for posting your data. Unfortunately, the data you have is not regularly sampled, hence the irregular shapes in the ListDensityPlot. However, you can interpolate and resample if you want "square" blocks. Below, `data` is your data from pastebin.

```
if = Interpolation[data];
ListDensityPlot[
 Flatten[Table[{x, y, if[x, y]}, {x, 1, 23, 2}, {y, 1, 14}], 1],
 InterpolationOrder -> 0
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for idea, but in my case it returns not only squares, what's weird because values are different

Comment: @pupilx You should add your data and the results in the question, so we can compare results.

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: @pupilx Thank you for the data. I have amended my answer. Take a look at the new version.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot. The most important for me is not to lose information if value < 1, because then I need to construct true/false matrix , will it be ok?

Comment: @pupilx Which value are you referring to? In any case, I'd suggest generating a fake data set containing a few "problem points", and playing with it to see what results you get.